# how do i handle the deadlock from mysql command: show engine innodb status

Tags: mysql

following is result of mysql command : show engine innodb status:
but i don't get it to find where deadlock actualy occured and how to prevent it please help:

------------------------ LATEST DETECTED DEADLOCK ------------------------ 170718 10:55:33 *** (1) TRANSACTION: TRANSACTION 2999, ACTIVE 36 sec inserting mysql tables in use 1, locked 1 LOCK WAIT 5 lock struct(s), heap size 1248, 3 row lock(s), undo log entries 4 MySQL thread id 13644, OS thread handle 0x7f505411a700, query id 344680 136.243.199.41 shareblastdbuser update

```
 insert into `messages_all` (`message_unique_id_fk`,        `user_profile_id_fk`, `user_account_id_fk`, `user_profile_type`, `message_caption`, `message_type_flag`, `media_filename_original`, `message_source`, `message_mode`, `image_cdn_id`, `video_cdn_id`, `user_public_ip_address`, `user_ip_address`, `media_mime_type`, `message_hash_sha512`, `message_hash2_sha512`, `original_all_datetime`, `sha512_ismatch`, `dedup_ms_mi_score_round`, `dedup_ms_mi_ismatch`, `dedup_ms_mi_matchid`, `dedup_ms_mi_score`, `dedup_ms_ai_sourcevalue`, `dedup_ms_ai_contentid`) values (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, NOW(), ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)
```

*** (1) WAITING FOR THIS LOCK TO BE GRANTED: RECORD LOCKS space id 23 page no 13962 n bits 880 index `messages_unique_ibfk_9` of table `shareblastdb`.`messages_all` trx id 2999 lock_mode X insert intention waiting Record lock, heap no 1 PHYSICAL RECORD: n_fields 1; compact format; info bits 0 0: len 8; hex 73757072656d756d; asc supremum;;

```
 insert into `messages_all` (`message_unique_id_fk`, `user_profile_id_fk`, `user_account_id_fk`, `user_profile_type`, `message_caption`, `message_type_flag`, `media_filename_original`, `message_source`, `message_mode`, `image_cdn_id`, `video_cdn_id`, `user_public_ip_address`, `user_ip_address`, `media_mime_type`, `message_hash_sha512`, `message_hash2_sha512`, `original_all_datetime`, `sha512_ismatch`, `dedup_ms_mi_score_round`, `dedup_ms_mi_ismatch`, `dedup_ms_mi_matchid`, `dedup_ms_mi_score`, `dedup_ms_ai_sourcevalue`, `dedup_ms_ai_contentid`) values (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, NOW(), ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)
```

*** (2) HOLDS THE LOCK(S): RECORD LOCKS space id 23 page no 13962 n bits 880 index `messages_unique_ibfk_9` of table `shareblastdb`.`messages_all` trx id 29A9 lock_mode X Record lock, heap no 1 PHYSICAL RECORD: n_fields 1; compact format; info bits 0 0: len 8; hex 73757072656d756d; asc supremum;;

*** (2) WAITING FOR THIS LOCK TO BE GRANTED: RECORD LOCKS space id 23 page no 13962 n bits 880 index `messages_unique_ibfk_9` of table `shareblastdb`.`messages_all` trx id 29A9 lock_mode X insert intention waiting Record lock, heap no 1 PHYSICAL RECORD: n_fields 1; compact format; info bits 0 0: len 8; hex 73757072656d756d; asc supremum;;

*** WE ROLL BACK TRANSACTION

Comment: SHOW GLOBAL VARIABLES LIKE 'tx_isolation'. What does this show?

Comment: its REPEATABLE-READ

Comment: Deadlocks do happen, you cannot fully prevent them. The question is: how you handle it.

Comment: yes, means what changes should i make to handle this type of situation

Comment: i am getting this type of errors :SQLSTATE[40001]: Serialization failure: 1213 Deadlock found when trying to get lock; try restarting transaction

Comment: Catch the error in the application logic and either restart the rolled back transaction or let the user know that sg went astray and let it decide what to do.

Comment: i also get this type of error:General error: 1205 Lock wait timeout exceeded; try restarting transaction (SQL: insert into `

Comment: i also have doubt why ' ?'  occured in my tables insertion queries